# A second created Blazor Hybrid App displays HTML from a different Blazor Hybrid App project

Tags: c#, android, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a second Blazor Hybrid App using the following docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/walkthroughs/build-first-hybrid-app

But when debugging on my Android phone I see what appears to be part of a HTML Link tag referencing another Blazor Hybrid App I had been working on previously (see bottom of img):

[image: 2nd project]

If I search for that *"_content/**/css/main.css"* in my 2nd project that string does not exist anywhere, this does exist in my first project:

[image: main.css]

I had thought I copied it over by accident, but apparently not.

Where is this string coming from??

Comment: How do you host/deploy this?  Most obvious answer is that it is cached somewhere.

Comment: vulpenie try <Ctrl>+F5 to clear the cache.  As Henk suggested maybe the browser is caching the page from the first program.

Comment: Well the bizarre thing is that the screen shot is of the app when deployed on my android phone (you can kinda see the top android bar where battery and time would be where i snipped the pic at the top). So I cant Ctrl+F5 this either :S

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have uninstalled the first Blazor Hybrid project from my android phone as well, but no change. Are they sharing some cache on the android phone - i would have thought they are isolated in storage.

Comment: Do you have a `wwwroot/service-worker.js` that is caching your application as a [Progressive Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: @jhr No i dont have this file :( I have not converted the project to a PWA project either.

i have meerly created the following:
`dotnet new blazorhybrid -o FirstBlazorHybridApp`
`dotnet new blazorhybrid -o SecondBlazorHybridApp`

And this second app has html displayed on screen from the first app after deployed to my android device :S